# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 When I try to access a method to input data to an array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I am very new to Java, I would like some help in regards to my problem.

I have 3 different Classes, on my main class would be where I call my method from my Team() class. This is the method that I would be calling:

```
public void addMember(Member membersAdd){

   members[memberCnt] = membersAdd;
   memberCnt++;
   
}
```

and this is the code on my main class for calling the method:

```
                Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("\n" + "Enter Name: ");
                tempName = sc2.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
                tempAge = sc2.nextInt();
                Member membersAddBB = new Member (tempName, tempAge);
                
                boolean checkQualificationBB = basketball.checkQualification(membersAddBB);
                if(checkQualificationBB == true){
                    if (basketball.memberCnt < basketball.maxMember){
                        
                        
                        basketball.addMember(membersAddBB);
```

Which is enclosed within a switch.

When I try running the program. It shows an error of

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

I tried some stuffs, and tried adding

```
Member [] members = new Member[maxMember];
```

in my addMember method at the very start. It worked in accepting the variables I input in it, but when I input another variable the first variable would be gone and be null. Example: index 0 would be converted into null if I called it again to add a value on index 1.

I am having a hard time in this part of my program, it would be nice to help me out to solve the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error.

Sorry I am new to Java.. still learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exceeding the size of the array (arrays are fixed sized). You need to initalize a array like the following before you can add anything to it.

```
Member[] members = new Member[10]; // 10 members.
```

But eventually you may exceed that so I suggest you use an `ArrayList<Memmber>` since Lists grow dynamically as needed.  Or you can do the following to copy the array and update its size as needed.  Requires an `import java.util.Arrays;`

```
public void addMember(Member membersAdd){
    if (memberCnt >= members.length) {
    // copy array and increase size by 10.
     members = Arrays.copyOf(members, members.length+10);
    }
    members[memberCnt] = membersAdd;
    memberCnt++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much WJS! It worked well with the copy of array. Its the first time I heard about  ArrayList, I would take time to study about it. For the mean time I tried your second solution, and tried to output the contents of my array, it worked well. Thank you again!